# Mocha 'before each hook' message in red. How do I know what specifically is wrong?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js

I have the following message, just before a failing test:

```
1) "before each" hook
```

**That is the the entire message**. It is in red, which makes me think there is something wrong with the before each hook, but I'm unsure of what the error is. It could be:

- A failed timeout
- A failed assertion
- An Error being thrown

How do I know what the error is?

This particular `beforeEach()` normally executes perfectly fine.

Comment: Could you post your beforeEach code?

Comment: @victorkohl My beforeEach code requires understanding of an external API (these are integration tests) and would distract the conversation from the question: what does this message mean?

Comment: If the hook is asynchronous do you call callback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this problem when in the beforeEach I accidentally called done() twice (I called it once at the end of the beforeEach, but also called it again via an async function called in the beforeEach).

When I ran the tests in watch mode I got the error message you described without any additional information; when I ran the tests normally I did not get any errors. I reported this on [a related ticket](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/1588).

Answer (score 3):

> How do I know what the error is?

Debug it just like you would any normal code. If you are making assertions inside a `beforeEach` callback, you are abusing the framework. Assertions belong in the `it` callbacks, so refactor that.

It's also probably not just forgetting to call `done` because mocha has a clear error message when that happens.

Thus your code is probably throwing an uncaught exception and you can use your favorite flavor of debugging to track it down. I like running mocha with `--debug-brk` and [debugging with node-inspector](http://peterlyons.com/jsDebug), but some `console.log` statements should also suffice. Note passing only the relevant test file to mocha and using the `describe.only` or `it.only` techniques can keep the test suite small and focused while you track down the root cause.

Comment: The workaround presented is what I've done - moving the beforeEach() into tests, debugging there, fixing it and putting back into my code - but this would be better as a comment since it isn't actually an answer. Also: node-inspector is broken on current (0.12 - see https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/issues/535) and previous (0.10 has bugs in v8) versions of node at the time of writing.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening due to the time limit exceeding. In mocha, 2000ms is the maximum time allocated for an async process. So to make your code successful, you to increase the time limit
It is usually done by using the code:

```
this.timeout(4000)
```

Note: you can't use the arrow function because you can't use the

> this

option in arrow function.

Comment: For async functions you can add `.timeout(4000)` to the end of the test:

`it('should test this async stuff...', async () => { ... }).timeout(4000)`

Answer (score 0):

For each of your tests, when you want to append the end call,

dont use:

```
.end(done())
```

use:

```
.end(done)
```